# How to print all the values using linq?

Tags: linq, windows-phone-7

I have got a listbox and I have to populate that with the elements from the query. The query is,

```
var query = from b in context.table select b; 
 List<Tab> reclist = q.ToList();
```

using LINQ how can I print all the obtained values in the listbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to create a `DataTemplate` containing a `TextBlock` whose `Text` property you bind to a property on your object. So, some XAML something like;

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyListBox">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Presuming your `Tab` class has a property called `Name`. Obviously if it doesn't you'll want to change the `{Binding Name}` portion of the XAML to match the property name that you want to display in the `ListBox`.

You then bind to your item;

```
MyListBox.ItemsSource = reclist;
```

Comment: I've done all of the above suggestion, still it returns empty listbox.

Comment: Sorry sir, My mistake... I checked again and everything works exceptionally fine. Thanks a lot